# Fibonacci Sequence using loop and recur

Tags: clojure, fibonacci

I am doing the Project Euler challenge in Clojure and I want to find the sum of all the even numbers in a fibonacci sequence up to a certain number.

The code for a function that does this is below. I know there are quicker and easier ways of doing this, I am just experimenting with recursion using loop and recur. However the code doesn't seem to work it never returns an answer.

```
(defn fib-even-sum [upto]
  (loop [previous 1 nxt 1 sum 0]
    (if (or (<= upto 1) (>= nxt upto))
     sum)
    (if (= (mod nxt 2) 0)
       (recur nxt (+ previous nxt) (+ sum nxt))
       (recur nxt (+ previous nxt) sum))))
```

I was not sure if I could do recur twice in the same loop or not. I'm not sure if this is causing the problem?

Comment: I was looking into that predicate. I'm going to change the code to use it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: there is a `fibs` in `'clojure.contrib.lazy-seqs` which is quite fast. With that, the problem can be expressed like this: `(reduce + (filter #(even? %) (take-while #(< % 4000000) (fibs))))` .. some of the other Euler Problems can be done as one-liners as well, enjoy! :-)

Comment: Just an alternative (know you weren't looking for one, so it's in a comment!)    (def fibo (map second 
                       (iterate (fn [[x y]] [y (+ x y)]) [0 1])))

Comment: @IsaacHodes Yikes, don't do that. If you def it at the top-level, it can never get GCed. Instead, `(defn fib0 [] (map ...))` and call fib0 whenever you need a new copy of the sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a misplaced closing paren in the first IF (after `sum`)...

```
(defn fib-even-sum [upto]
  (loop [previous 1 nxt 1 sum 0]
    (if (or (<= upto 1) (>= nxt upto))
        sum
        (if (= (mod nxt 2) 0)
           (recur nxt (+ previous nxt) (+ sum nxt))
           (recur nxt (+ previous nxt) sum)))))
```

Now it works and fast

Comment: Thanks. I see the problem. Works great now.

Comment: This is a common problem for new lisp coders, by the way.

If I were writing this, I'd replace the `(if a x (if b y z))` pattern with a use of `cond`: `(cond a x, b y, :else z)`. But of course you should learn at your own pace, and not worry about form if you're still learning the function.